# Sets of matrices with differences invertible with high probability

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ be a subset of square matrices over a finite field of size $q$, and suppose a probability distribution is defined on $S$.
The goal is to construct non-trivial (eg with $n\neq 1$) sets $S$ with corresponding distributions such that upon independently sampling two elements $s,s'\leftarrow S$, their difference $s-s'$ is non-invertible with probability strictly less than $1/|\mathbb{F}|=1/q$.

For a non-example, let $S=\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ with the uniform distribution.
There are $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n-q^i)$ invertible elements in $S$.
For any $s\in S$ the number of $s'\in S$ such that $s-s'$ is non-invertible is the same as the number of non-invertible elements of $S$.
Therefore, $s-s'$ is non-invertible with probability
$$
1-\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n-q^i)\Big/q^{n^2} > 1\big/q
$$

Any research in this direction?
Any ideas for constructing such sets?
Any proof such sets don't exist?
I'm hoping that requiring differences to be invertible with high probability allows for more options than requiring all differences to be invertible.
If you have comments for a similar problem formulated over infinite fields I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: If you select $S$ to be the set of matrices representing multiplication by any element of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ with resepect to a chosen basis, then $s-s'$ will be invertible whenever $s\neq s'$. The set $S$ then has $q^n$ elements, and the sought after probability is $1/q^n$. This may not be what you want, because all the non-zero differences really are invertible, but I bring it up for you to comment and clarify.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A perfect example, so simple, thank you! I wish that could be generalized, finding a set of linearized permutation polynomials closed under subtraction, but I'm having no luck with that. The bigger $S$ is the better, but I wouldn't be surprised if $q^n$ is the limit.

Comment: $1/q^n$ is a natural limit in the following sense. Fix a non-zero vector $x\in\Bbb{F}_q^n$. There are then $q^n$ possible values for $s(x)$. Whenever  $s(x)=s'(x)$, we can immediately conclude that $s-s'$ cannot be invertible because it has a non-trivial kernel. It is worth observing that in the construction using the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$, this argument works irrespective of the choice of $x$. For a more random collection $S$, you would expect the choice to matter.

Comment: I can't see the dependence on $x$. Regardless of $S$, $|S|$ can be at most $q^n$, otherwise for *any* $x$ there exists $s,s'\in S$ with $s(x)=s'(x)$.